# Can a signal in one thread, interrupt sleep period of another thread of the same process in linux

Tags: linux, sleep, pthreads

There are two threads (parent thread and child thread, both runs in their own infinite loop) in a process. The parent thread does only one work, i.e. to continuously (`while(1)`) check the system time for 00.00 hrs, to change file name every day. So for each check, I have put 60 seconds sleep to minimize cpu usage by the thread.
And the child thread has its own timer alarms (independent of parent thread) and a timer signal handler (the alarms are set for within 10 seconds, so there may be many timer signals while parent thread sleeping for 60 seconds).
Now the problem I am facing is the parent thread is not sleeping for 60 seconds, as I observed it sleeps less than 10 seconds and goes for checking the system time multiple times in a minute.
what is the reason for the situation? and **how to solve it**?

Thank you.

Comment: That signal may be delivered to the parent thread. Each thread of one process has its own signal mask, you might want to mask the corresponding signal in the parent thread.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you check every 60 seconds if it is midnight?  In the simple case, just sleep for ~24 hours.  If you need precision, first compute when it will next be midnight, then sleep for that long minus a few ms.

Comment: Instead of signal handlers, setup the signal handling via `signalfd` instead of `sigaction` and poll on a file descriptor.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You obvious are not a developer. The fun of developing is complicating stuff. ;-P

Comment: @WilliamPursell, even if I sleep for 60*60*24 seconds (`sleep(60*60*24);`), the problem remains. isn't it?. When I use sleep(60), I expect it to sleep for exactly 60 seconds, not more or less. How to do that? why sleep time is not exact to what I specified.

Comment: @reddihari because signal handling in a multi-threaded environment is fraught with peril, and your sleeps are implemented with signals.